# Calling a private method xxx using self.xxx() from within another private method resulting in error "private method `xxx' called"

Tags: ruby, private

I'm trying to get a good Ruby coding style. To prevent accidently calling a local variable with the same name, I'm always using `self.` where appropriate. But now I stumbled over this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :sanitize_user_data

  private

  def sanitize_user_data
    self.sanitize_name # with ".self" it's a problem, without it's not!
  end

  def sanitize_name
    unless self.name.nil?
      self.name.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')
      self.name.strip!
    end
  end
end
```

The above code results in an error

> private method `sanitize_name` called

but when removing `self.` and just using `sanitize_name`, it works. Why's that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver, and saying `self.sanitize_name` is explicitly specifying the object (`self`) that should receive `sanitize_name`, rather than relying on the implicit receiver (which is also `self`).

You can't avoid this, you either need to call plain old `sanitize_name` without an explicit receiver, or do `self.send(:sanitize_name)`. I'm not sure that always explicitly specifying `self` is really "good style", but that's subjective. If you want to ensure you're calling a method instead of a variable, add parenthesis:

```
def a; "method"; end
a = "variable"
a() #=> "method"
a   #=> "variable"
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I will keep this in mind, but I guess to really understand it, I would have to dig deeply into Ruby's internals, right?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Not necessarily, it's just the way private methods work, by prohibiting an explicit receiver is can't be called from anywhere the implicit receiver is not the same `self`, it just has the somewhat unfortunate side effect of preventing you from calling a private method with the same explicit receiver as is the implicit receiver.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. Thanks a lot for explaining. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why's that?

By definition. Private methods can only be invoked by a receiverless message send, that's the *definition* of what `private` means.